# How to include a server-side timestamp in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Before firebase improvements I could post timestamps in any struct like

```
let usermsg =  ["CreatedAt":FirebaseServerValue.timestamp(), "ChatTitle":msg.ChatTitle,"ChatBody":msg.ChatBody,  "Owner":self.GoogleUserID]
```

But after `FIRServerValue.timestamp()` became ( `NSDictionary *`) I could not get timestamp to post as a value to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `["CreatedAt": [".sv": "timestamp"]...]`
The saved value for that key must be something like: 1464103942351